# Using Python as backend to Salesforce App

Tags: apex, callout, python

Python has some amazing libraries that I want to take advantage of. The only issue that I am concerned about here are the governor limits for long running operations.

I am creating a deduping app and operations such as Levenstein and Fuzzy Match are quadratic - Making it really easy to go over the governor limits.

The only alternative I can think of is using batch apex with callouts to a Flask App that can then run some python code as a way to stay within limitations.

Comment: This isn't exactly a question. What sort of answer are you looking for? Have you considered simply using [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) to perform your dedup logic? There's a lot of possible alternatives than just the one you're considering.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am looking for a way to run 100k Account records through an algorithm to find potential duplicates. I am doubtful that salesforce could handle such processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a possible way to bypass SF limits:

1) Make a callout to your server (do not wait for result).

2) On your server, after all calculations and any other actions make a callout to SF @RestResource with the actual answer.

3) Process answer on SF side.

Also sfdcfox is right, you can move logic dealing with duplicates to SF side by creating duplicate rules.